# Matrix representation of injective/surjective map from Rn to Rm

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-topology

I am reading differential topology and reading about the local immersion and local submersion theorem.

In the proof they made an assumption of the following:

let $h: R^n \rightarrow R^m$ be a injective linear map with $n \leq m$, then by a change of coordinate on $R^m$, we may assume $h$ has matrix representation of the form {$\frac{I_n}{0}$}. Which I take it as after we apply a change of coordinate on $R^n$ (choosing a different basis) we can assume the matrix representation of $h$ has that form.

Similarly if $f: R^n \rightarrow R^m$($n \geq m$) is subjective, linear then by C.O.C on $R^n$ we can assume $f$ has a matrix representation {${I_n | 0}$}.

I don't  understand why we must apply the change of coordinate on the domain(codomain) for injective (surjective) linear map instead of the other way around? Is it arbitrary?

Comment: You don't *have* to, but it makes the coming proofs easier.

Comment: Note that in the first case it should be change of basis in $\Bbb R^m$ (you changed the index in your following sentence) [row operations] and in the second case it should be change of basis in $\Bbb R^n$ [column operations].  You needn't apply a change of basis, but if you want to get that "normal form," you need to. :) It's useful to have that simple local formulation of what your function looks like.

Comment: Ted: I'm not saying I'm uncomfortable with the change of basis, my confusion is why I need to apply the C.O.B to $R^m$ for the first case and $R^n$ for the second case. instead of the other way around.

Comment: Can someone explain, for example in the case of surjective f, how exactly would you prove that C.O.B can induce such a map? I am at a lost even after a few hours...